# How to see call durations in call hierarchical way in Azure Application Insights?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

Is there any way in Azure Application Insights to get processing durations for an API call in its method calls hierarchical pattern ?

I mean, the outer most call should be at the root and should be account for complete call duration, and then inner statements or calls should show the break up of that complete duration, and this should go on deeper for more inner calls.

Comment: If you mean only function calls, and not like nested API calls, the Profiler in App Insights could be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Application Insights have two hierarchical views - dependency calls across many components:

[image]

And Profiler Trace (within one component):

[image]